# Why does my template literal not create a new line?

Tags: javascript, html

```
var request = require("request");
request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1", function(
  error,
  response,
  body
) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    //Things worked!
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(parsedData);
    document.getElementById(
      "text"
    ).innerHTML = `${parsedData.name} lives in Saint John NB. 
     Her street name is ${parsedData.address.street}`; //This should be a new line??????
  }
});
```

Can someone explain why there is not a new line in my template literal here?

Comment: Why do you think there's no newline in the literal?

Comment: When you put it into `innerHTML`, the browser does its own line wrapping, just like normal HTML.

Comment: element now has  \n    not   <BR>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template literal does contain a newline. But when the browser renders the HTML, it re-wraps the line.

If you want to see the text without being reformatted, put it in a `<pre>` element or set the style of the element to `white-space: pre;` with CSS.

Or use `<br>` in the HTML:

```
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    //Things worked!
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(parsedData);
    document.getElementById(
      "text"
    ).innerHTML = `${parsedData.name} lives in Saint John NB.<br>
     Her street name is ${parsedData.address.street}`; //This should be a new line??????
  }
```

Or assign to `.innerText` instead of `.innerHTML`, this retains newlines (but not other formatting like indentation).

Comment: or he could just use innerText if that's all he's rendering and not HTML.

Comment: @ArberSylejmani I think innerText still gets line wrapping, it just shows HTML tags and entities literally.

Comment: Thank you! This helped very much.